# Sort hosts file by TLD domain, not by suffix (.com.whatever) or prefix (subdomains)

Tags: perl, sorting, unix, terminal

I need to sort a super huge half-mil entries list of domain names in a host file. But I want to sort them not by subdomains or by the .com .net.

So this:

```
www.apple3.com
this.apple4.com
that.apple1.uk
and.that.apple2.com.br
```

Will turn into this:

```
that.apple1.uk
and.that.apple2.com.br
www.apple3.com
this.apple4.com
```

No ips yet on this list (as all will resolve to 0.0.0.0, I'll add that later) just the domains are in the list. I'm using a Mac with brew, so I can use any GNU or nix tool for it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So `apple2.com.br` is a subdomain? What rule do you use to decide what  is the subdomain part of the domain name?

Comment: Recent versions of the IO::Socket::SSL module include [IO::Socket::SSL::PublicSuffix](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL::PublicSuffix) which you can use to get the public suffix (i.e `com.br`) or the root domain (one level up, i.e. `apple2.com.br`) to a domain. Once you have this you can just sort by this. The documentation of the module contains an example on how to get to the root domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to efficient sorting in Perl is to create a function that transforms the value to sort into a representative string that can be sorted lexicographically.

For example, if you want to sort dates, you could transform them into the `yyyymmdd` format. In this case, we'll reorder the parts of the domain such that

```
foo.bar.apple1.co.uk
```

becomes one of the following:

```
# Using this approach, the sorted order of apple1.com and apple1.net will vary.
apple1.bar.foo
```

```
# Using this approach, the sorted order of apple1.com and apple1.net will be consistent.
apple1.bar.foo<NUL>uk.co
```

We want the numbers to be sort naturally, (1, 2, 10 rather than 1, 10, 2). Our key function could handle that, but we'll take the easy way out by replacing `sort` with `natkeysort` from [Sort::Key::Natural](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Sort::Key::Natural). As a bonus, `natkeysort` allows us to easily integrate our key function!

The hard part is to identify the suffix. There's no rule for that, just constantly changing definitions. As such, we'll use a module to identify the suffix.

---

Implementing the key function using [Domain::PublicSuffix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Domain::PublicSuffix):

```
use feature qw( state );

use Domain::PublicSuffix qw( );

sub get_sort_key {
   my ($host) = @_;
   $host =~ s/\.\z//;
   state $dps = Domain::PublicSuffix->new();
   $dps->get_root_domain($host)
      or die "$host: ".$dps->error();

   my @name   = split /\./, substr($host, 0, -length($dps->suffix())-1);
   my @suffix = split /\./, $dps->suffix();
   return join('.', reverse @name)."\0".join('.', reverse @suffix);
}
```

---

Implementing the key function using [IO::Socket::SSL::PublicSuffix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Socket::SSL::PublicSuffix):

```
use feature qw( state );

use IO::Socket::SSL::PublicSuffix qw( );

sub get_sort_key {
   my ($host) = @_;
   my @host = split(/\./, $host);
   state $ps = IO::Socket::SSL::PublicSuffix->default();
   my ($name, $suffix) = $ps->public_suffix(\@host);
   return join('.', reverse @$name)."\0".join('.', reverse @$suffix);
}
```

---

The above functions are used as follows:

```
use feature qw( say );

use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natkeysort );

my @hosts = (
   'www.apple3.net',
   'www.apple3.com',
   'this.apple4.com',
   'that.apple4.com',
   'www.apple10.com',
   'that.apple1.uk',
   'and.that.apple2.com.br',
);

my @sorted_hosts = natkeysort { get_sort_key($_) } @hosts;

say for @sorted_hosts;
```

Output:

```
that.apple1.uk
and.that.apple2.com.br
www.apple3.com
www.apple3.net
that.apple4.com
this.apple4.com
www.apple10.com
```

[IO::Socket::SSL::PublicSuffix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Socket::SSL::PublicSuffix) is supposedly updated more often than [Domain::PublicSuffix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Domain::PublicSuffix) (and [Mozilla::PublicSuffix](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Mozilla::PublicSuffix)), but it's part of a larger distro.

Comment: GREAT! Thanks ikegami. The script complained about some 2 dozens of domains not being valid, some were, but that was easy to edit out. In the end the PublicSuffix one served me very well. 450k domains that provide ads spam junkware and other not desireble 'wares' were sorted. I'll now check them all to see the ones alive and compile the final list. THANKS!